# What kind of exceptions should go in DLQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am using AWS lambda subscribed to a SNS Topic and attached a DLQ in lambda in case lambda throws any error. There are broadly 2 kind of exceptions that can happen in this lambda:

1. Say, in lambda, I got a error which is due to wrong input, should that also go in DLQ? This exception won't be retriable as it requires some change in the input format.
2. I got a exception due to unavailability of some resource. This error is retriable and can be fixed by retries?

Which kind of exceptions should we store in DLQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not messages go in a DLQ should not depend on the type of error. It should depend on the data integrity requirements of your application.

Suppose you have an application that consumes minutely messages from many weather sensors, and you’re building up a set of historical data so that you can use it in some predictive model. In this case, a few lost messages are not a big deal, because any individual data point is not very meaningful. (In fact, you probably want to filter out the most extreme outliers anyway.) In this case, you should log all of the errors and set an alarm to go off if you drop more than X% of messages in Y time period. (Too many dropped messages could indicate a systemic problem.)

On the other hand, if your Lambda consumes messages from electronic badge readers so that you can have a security record of who accessed the secure parts of a building, then you want to put all messages with errors in a DLQ. In this case, completeness of the data is very important, and when there’s an error, you need to fix it and resend the messages.

Finally, it’s important to mention that a DLQ is not really meant for storage. Think of it more like the `catch` in a `try`/`catch` block.  So another consideration for when to use a DLQ is whether you have some sort of path to recovery. If the messages are doctor appointment reminders which your application uses to contact patients to remind them of their upcoming appointment, then you might have a Lambda that calls their phone with a recorded message, but if the phone line is unavailable or the phone number is invalid, the message can go to a DLQ where another Lambda can consume the message and try sending an email reminder instead.